# Xamarin.Forms project with all 4 platforms

Tags: android, ios, macos, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am willing to have one single solution for all platform project.

For now, if I use Visual Studio 2019 Windows, then I can have iOS, Android and UWP
And if, I use Visual Studio for MAC, then I can have iOS, Android and MacOS

I am willing to have one common project and share source code via GitHub Repository (obviously private) and then add all 4 platforms into it.

I already had a running project on VS 2019 Windows, and when I shared the Source code using GitHub to VS MAC, after adding MacOS its not working.

I know I am suppose to ask questions related to coding, and I assume this is indirectly related to that only.

Can anyone guide me, how to do that properly. I am using Syncfusion Xamarin.Forms controls as well.

Comment: I created Xamrin.Forms solution and add the macOS client project in Mac  then copy the solution to Windows. I could open it success and contain MacOS project. Does your problem only occur during copy the code from github?

Comment: And you could try  this test app that contains 4 [platforms](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/myTestApp).

Comment: I am not sure, might be the issue due to Syncfusion Controls then, may be they are not supported fully with Xamarin.Forms

Can anyone suggest good controls like Syncfusion (free ofcourse as I am using Community Edition)?

Comment: It seems the issue is with the Acr.UserDialogs as its not supported for MacOS as of now.